# index.d.ts exists but not being picked up after npm install

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a vite reactjs typescript component library that I published to npm but after installing it in a new project with npm install, I get this warning and couldn't compile:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'c-forms'. 'app/node_modules/c-forms/dist/c-forms.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at 'app/node_modules/c-forms/dist/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'c-forms' library may need to update its package.json or typings.
```

My package.json is

```
    {
  "name": "c-forms",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.cjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],


  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/c-forms.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/c-forms.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css",
    "./dist/index.d.ts": "./dist/index.d.ts"
  },
  "main": "./dist/c-forms.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/c-forms.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.64",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "@types/validator": "^13.11.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.36",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.6",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.7.3",
    "vite-plugin-lib-inject-css": "^2.0.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "dist/index.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

tsconfig.node.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts","package.json"],
}
```

and vite config is

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import * as packageJson from './package.json'
import { resolve } from "node:path";

import { libInjectCss } from 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css';


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(),
    libInjectCss(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
      rollupTypes: true,
    }),
  
  ]


  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve('src', 'index.ts'),
      name: 'CForms',
      formats: ['es', 'umd'],
      fileName: (format) => `c-forms.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies), 
        "react", "react-dom"],
        output: {
          globals: {
            react: "React",
            "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
          },
        },
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
})
```

I can see es and umd generated, along with index.d.ts file with all declarations but not sure client apps cant use the library.

Comment: Try adding `types: "./dist/index.d.ts"` in the `.` key under `exports`in `package.json`. As a sibling of `import` and `require`

Comment: @adsy please put it as an answer so i mark it as one. worked! thanks so much.

Comment: Great! I've formalised it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/c-forms.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/c-forms.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css",
    "./dist/index.d.ts": "./dist/index.d.ts"
  },
```

To the following.

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/c-forms.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/c-forms.umd.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css",
    "./dist/index.d.ts": "./dist/index.d.ts"
  },
```

This ensures that bundlers and such know which type definition file relates to the other files defined in that block.